# swipebox.js - swiping or navigating slides in reverse order not possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

When loading slides dynamically (http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/), it does not seem possible to swipe right to load the last slide and cycle through the slides in reverse order. Currently I can only swipe left to view each slide in the specified order.

Here is my current code:

```
jQuery( '.images' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.swipebox( [
        { href:'image1.jpg' },
        { href:'image2.jpg' },
        { href:'image3.jpg' },
        { href:'image4.jpg' },
        { href:'image5.jpg' },
        { href:'image6.jpg' }
    ] );
} );
```

This loads image1.jpg and moves through each slide in order. It is not able to move from image1.jpg to image6.jpg in reverse.

Any possible workarounds or solutions known for this issue?

Comment: I'm looking to the swipebox options in the [documentation](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/#options):
setting `loopAtEnd: true` does the job, no ?

Comment: Thanks, yes that will continue the slide from 6 to 1 when you reach the end, but the problem is still having the option to go in reverse order from the start (1 to 6).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I tried myself. Then you may need to hack the source..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a few the [source code](https://github.com/brutaldesign/swipebox/blob/master/src/js/jquery.swipebox.js). In the function `getPrev` you can implement the same logic as in the function `getNext`, with a new option, let's call it `enableReverse`. You will set it to `true` as a regular option when calling the plug-in (don't forget to add a default value to the `defaults` object).
You will end up with something like:

```
getPrev : function () {
  var index = $( '#swipebox-slider .slide' ).index( $( '#swipebox-slider .slide.current' ) ), src;
  if ( index > 0 ) {
    // normal implementation
  } else {
    if ( plugin.settings.enableReverse === true ) {
      // get inspired by getNext function and use the correct indexes
    } else {
      // normal implementation
    }
  }
}
```

You will also have to change the condition at the end of `setSlide` function so that the 'prev' button is not disabled:

```
if ( index === 0 )
```

becomes:

```
if ( index === 0 && plugin.settings.enableReverse !== true )
```

hope this will help !

Comment: Thanks for tip! Definitely moving in the right direction. I've got the custom code implemented but I'm missing something...

`} else if ( plugin.settings.enableReverse === true ) {
        src = $( '#swipebox-slider .slide' ).eq( index ).contents().find( 'iframe' ).attr( 'src' );
     $( '#swipebox-slider .slide' ).eq( index ).contents().find( 'iframe' ).attr( 'src', src );
     index++;
                    $this.preloadMedia( index );
     $this.setSlide( index );
     $this.preloadMedia( index - 1 );
     if ( plugin.settings.prevSlide ) {
      plugin.settings.prevSlide();
     }`

Comment: @oneder your `else if` means that here `index > 0` is not `true`, i.e. `index <= 0`, thus you need to set it equal to the last element: `index = elements.length-1` (not doing `index++`)

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks for your help!